# select multiple checkbox inside listbox by row clicking in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to select multiple checkboxes inside a listbox by clinking the row. it's working fine when click performs on checkbox content.
Xaml:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" 
                          Margin="0 2 0 0"
                          Style="{StaticResource BaseCheckBox}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This seems like a use case where a DataGrid is better suited

Comment: @MindSwipe just trying to select checkboxes by row clicking same like checkbox content clicking.

Comment: And why not use a DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your listbox items only contain checkboxes, you can force those `CheckBox`es to occupy the full item's width:

```
<CheckBox 
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>
```

If your listbox items also contain some other elements, things get more complicated.

You can e.g. bind the `IsSelected` property of each `ListBoxItem` to your data item's `IsSelected` property:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then, you will be able to check the checkboxes by selecting the items in the listbox. However, the checked items will also be in a selected state.

If you don't like or don't need that, you can remove the selection visual style:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>

        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Yes, there is the only checkbox in the list box and the first solution work for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution of this problem:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```